# svn export makes my page blank

Tags: php, apache, svn, codeigniter, centos

I'm using LAMP with CodeIgniter for one of my projects; version controlled by SVN. Every time I execute `svn export file:///svnrepo/project/trunk/www . --force` when in the www directory and then reload the web page, it goes blank.

The website only shows up after I do a `service httpd restart` (Using CentOS 5).

I want to be able to execute the svn export using a Phing build script in the future and I don't want to have to get root privileges and restart apache every time when I do a build.

Is what I'm experience a common problem? How do I solve it without restarting apache?

**Edit:**
It seems someone has had this problem before: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/181642/

Comment: I've looked around. This could potentially be a APC caching problem.

Comment: I can confirm this as well. Disabling APC cache fixed the issue. I installed APC through my package manager. Perhaps install through PECL would avoid this problem? For the time being I'm just restarting the web server after the svn export.

Comment: White page = fatal error. Find out what the fatal error is and edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it.SVN maintains a files last modified time which throws off the APC cache. So to solve it we update the last modified time of all the files after we run an SVN export. Here is my final script:

```
#!/bin/sh
svn export --force file:///home/steve/repo/exmaple/trunk \
 /home/steve/public_html/example.com/public/
find /home/steve/public_html/exmaple.com/public | xargs touch
```

You can find more details [here](http://sameerparwani.com/posts/mixing-subversion-and-apc-for-php).

Comment: I seem to get "touch: invalid option -- 'T'" as a result of that last find <basepath> piped to "xargs touch"...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to set apc.stat=0 ([reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.stat)) in the apc.ini, and then use `apc_clear_cache()` ([reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-clear-cache.php)) to force the removal of the opcode cache.

What's awesome about this solution is that when `apc.stat` is set to 0, it disables the check on each request to determine if the file has been modified. This results in a huge performance boost.

Additionally, using `apc_clear_cache()` to clear the APC cache tends to result in a cleaner build. I've run into wonky race conditions where certain files will get built out that have dependencies on others that have not yet been built out. This results in a spat of FATAL errors. The only caveat here is that `apc_clear_cache()` needs to be run via apache, so you'll need to implement a `wget`or something similar for this.

Comment: If I turn off apc.stat, does this mean that an emergency change in the code will result in APC not recognizing the change? Therefore I would have to clear the cache every time I make a small change to the code (without redoing a whole build)?

Comment: That's correct. The downside of this method is that you need to perform a full build (svn export + cache clear), for every php change, no matter how tiny. It's ideal for sites that get built infrequently (a few times a day). If you're making changes to your production site every few minutes, this is not a great method. But it really depends on your workflow.